# SDL Seg Fault in blitting loop

Tags: segmentation-fault, sdl

Okay, so I have this code which just iterates through my object array blitting what needs to be blitted:

```
void Render()
{
    for(int Index = 0; Index < MAX_OBJECT_INSTANCES; Index++)
    {
        if(Game::ObjectArray[Index].IsActive() == false){}
        else
        {
            if(Game::ObjectArray[Index].IsHidden() == false)
            {
                SDL_BlitSurface(Game::ObjectArray[Index].CurrentSprite, NULL, Buffer::Screen, &Game::ObjectArray[Index].Position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had a look in the call stack and I found this:

```
0x681247d8  SDL_UpperBlit
```

I have no idea how to fix this. I should also note I am using SDL mixer and SDL image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run the code in a debugger.
2. Step into the `SDL_BlitSurface()` call.
3. Verify that the arguments are looking correct.
4. Keep stepping, to see what causes the segmentation fault.

I would suspect that one or more of the arguments is wrong/invalid.

Comment: I am completely lost. I have debugged it again and again and I still have no idea what's going on. If it's any help some of the objects in the array have not had it's variables set which might mean it'd turn up a null in the `SDL_Surface` variable. But it has never been a problem in the past. I don't know...